Twilio Voice Error Handling in case of application error has been occurs
I have setup Twilio Voice. any incoming call comes to twilio number is going to handle backend service which is running on instance with the /voice endpoint and same endpoint has been set up on twilio as well. Everything works fine, call handles well.
what I want is, in case of any application Error, either from backend logic or from twilio in parsing twiML (that has been sent by backend), Twilio will say "an Application Error has Occurs." and cut the call. but i want, in case of any error, twillo should transfer my call to given number, how can i achieve this ?
I have tried.try catch on my logic and in case of logic error, it will send  and call will be transfer, but what if error is not in logic, but in building the twilML.
